# c# algorithm to find nearest tile with specific type

Tags: c#, algorithm, grid-layout

Sorry for the title but i didn't know how to describe my problem in one sentence.

So basicly i am trying to create something to make random dungeons. I make rooms at random positions on a 2d grid and add doors to every room. Then I get the first door and try to find the closest other door but I can't find a good algorithm to this, I tried a modified version of a* and also looked at flood-fill but that isnt what I need. I was thinking of some sort of spiral around the first door and check every tile we pass to see if its a door. I have a list of all the doors in the level if that helps but there are a lot so i don't think it's a good idea to check the distance to every door.

Does anyone know if there is a good algorithm for this?

Comment: If you find the distance squared `(x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2)` instead of the distance `sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2))` there will be no use of square root to find this distance and will be a lot faster than checking a lot of tiles (of course it depends on the number of tiles to check and the number of doors to check).

Answer (score 0):

If a game stores its objects in a [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), searching of existing items in a scene prioritized by proximity could be done. Instead of searching for a collision, one can search for an object of a specific type. This can be done with the [`is` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) in C#. This question may be better suited for the [Game Development Stack Exchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

So you need to find the closest graph node with specific properties?

[BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) ( breadth-first search) is your friend.